# SelectSingleNode not working when going to Edit Xml File

Tags: c#, xml

I am editing a `XML file`. It has a document tag and I need to add a new tag inside it but my new tag is created after the closing document tag.

Here is what I tried:

```
XmlNode menu = XmlNode menu=doc.SelectSingleNode("Document"); 
XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ScreenOverlay", null); 
menu.AppendChild(node);
```

But using this code, my menu is always throwing a `null` value.

Comment: Please post a sample portion of your XML. Does it have namespaces? Does `doc.SelectSingleNode("//Document");` return the node (note the two leading slashes)

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer i used

```
XmlNode IPnode = new XmlDocument();

XmlNodeList List1 = doc.DocumentElement.GetElementsByTagName("Document");
XmlNode node = doc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ScreenOverlay", null);

   foreach (XmlNode nodeT in List1)
    {
         IPnode = nodeT;
   }
```

then

```
IPnode.AppendChild(node);
doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(IPnode);
```